# How to check what's inside of a docker image?

Tags: docker

Searching for a best-fit image for a project, you traverse the Docker's Hub and encounter many images. Depending on what they offer, you can choose between `slim`, `alpine`, `buster`, versioned images, `latest` image, etc.

How to see what's inside an image (what kind of layers are there)? Is it possible to list libraries and drivers contained in an image? How can I ensure my Redis image has proper drivers and libraries to work with Django? How to see if an image utilizes `apt`, `apt-get`, `apk` for package management, or if it doesn't provide such utility at all?

Also, I'd like to check it before fetching an image from Hub, if possible. Launching `docker run -it [...]` is a way to make such checks, but not very efficient if we have to download >1GB image beforehand.

Comment: Why not check the Dockerfile?

Comment: Looking at `latest` MariaDB Dockerfile we can see, that it uses `apt-get`, has `pwgen`, `tzdata` and `xz-utils` installed, but how can I know if it has those Django drivers as well? Maybe it's written somewhere implicitly, but I don't know how to find it.

Comment: Well, why do you assume it has those drivers if they aren't included in the Dockerfile?

Comment: When I installed the largest image I could find, it contained all the necessary libraries and drivers: I checked that after entering running container. Cons of this approach are that you have to download an image, the largest image isn't probably optimal for your use case and you have to assume the libs and drivers are there: none were listed explcitly in a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 6):

Can run an interactive shell container using that image and can check what are there inside the image.

`docker run -it image_name sh`

and once the image is built you can view all the layers that make up the image by running the below command

`docker history <image_id>`

To know what's there in each layer, you need to view the layers on the docker host at `/var/lib/docker/aufs`  *AUFS(Another Union FileSystem)*

The `/var/lib/docker/aufs` points to `diff`, `mnt`, `layers` directories.

1. Image layers and their contents are stored in the `diff` directory.
2. Running containers are mounted below the `mnt` directory (more explained below about mounts).
3. How image layers are stacked is in the `layers` directory.

*Can check [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) a tool for exploring docker image, layer contents etc*

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Is there also a way to check image contents **before** downloading it from Hub or any other source?

Comment: Can confirm that dive is a priceless little treasure.